# How do Dvait & Viśiṣṭādvaita explain Turiya?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

Turiya is said to be non-dual state of being Brahman as mentioned in several Upaniṣad-s.

I would like to see their official take on Turiya? Do they also consider Turiya being a non-dual state where the subject & object infuses? In that case, how do they square that with their inherently dualistic philosophies?

Comment: Turiya state where soul rest in lap of God.. so no issues..in case of dvaita but still God and Jiva are separate

Comment: @Prasanna You better might want to answer with proper reference(s).